# How do i pack a django module which has other django modules as dependencies?

Tags: python, django, deployment, dependency-management

I am developing a django module which is able to create UI interfaces to query a data repository. The module has an administration interface to configure the access to the data repository. For that it uses several other django modules such as `crispy_forms`.

Following the tutorial at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/reusable-apps/, I created a module and uploaded it to test.pypi.org. I can add the module dependencies and upon installing my module, `crispy_forms` and all other dependencies are installed. This all works fine.

But: in order to use my module, the user needs to make a lot of changes to the `settings.py` and `urls.py` files. Not only must my module be in INSTALLED_APPS but also my dependencies. Furthermore, to use `crispy_forms`, I need to specify a `CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK` setting. I always want this setting to be 'bootstrap4' and the user doesn't have to be aware of this setting.

So my question is: Is there a way that the inclusion of my module can take care of these dependencies?

What I need to have in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_module',
    'django_tables2',
    'crispy_forms',
    [...]
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
DJANGO_TABLES2_TEMPLATE = "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html"
```

What I would like in `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'my_module',
    [...]
]
```

Is there a way to achieve this? If I need to list all used modules in INSTALLED_APPS so be it, but I would really like to avoid that the user has to specify settings which they shouldn't change.